# Adding a Collapse - Expand All to an Accordion

Tags: javascript, html, css, accordion

Hi I've been trying to add an Collapse all to my accordion but can't seem to figure it out.. This is what I've been using: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_accordion.asp

I've been looking around but it seems like this accordion is different from most others so any help would be so very kind.

Here's my code:

```
<script>
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
  acc[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (panel.style.maxHeight){
      panel.style.maxHeight = null;
    } else {
      panel.style.maxHeight = panel.scrollHeight + "px";
    }
  });
}
</script>
```

CSS

```
.panel {
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: max-height 0.2s ease-in-out;
}
```

HTML

```
<article class="accordion">
  <div class="info" id="more">Office 123456</div>
  <div class="info" id="less">Exhibition</div>
  <div class="info" id="less">2017</div>
  <div class="info">Offset</div>
  <div class="info">169 x 239 mm</div>
</article>
<div class="panel">
  <div class="autoplay">
    <div><img src="img/01.jpg" alt=""></div>
    <div><img src="img/03.jpg" alt=""></div>
    <div><img src="img/04.jpg" alt=""></div>
  </div>
```

Comment: if you visit the link again you will see that you have not used all the css code

Comment: I have though I didnt include it in this post.. I after all asking what type of js I would need to include to be able to generate a collapse all button based on what I've done so far. Are you saying the css will help me here because I dont see how, care to explain?

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to achieve accordion. 
One of the ways you can do this is by using Jquery UI Library.

[jQuery UI collapsible demo link](https://jqueryui.com/accordion/#collapsible)

Download Link: http://jqueryui.com/download/

You can achieve collapsible accordion as follows:

Code:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>jQuery UI Accordion - Collapse content</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#accordion" ).accordion({
      collapsible: true
    });
  } );
  </script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="accordion">
  <h3>Section 1</h3>
  <div>
    <p>Mauris mauris ante, blandit et, ultrices a, suscipit eget, quam. Integer ut neque. Vivamus nisi metus, molestie vel, gravida in, condimentum sit amet, nunc. Nam a nibh. Donec suscipit eros. Nam mi. Proin viverra leo ut odio. Curabitur malesuada. Vestibulum a velit eu ante scelerisque vulputate.</p>
  </div>
  <h3>Section 2</h3>
  <div>
    <p>Sed non urna. Donec et ante. Phasellus eu ligula. Vestibulum sit amet purus. Vivamus hendrerit, dolor at aliquet laoreet, mauris turpis porttitor velit, faucibus interdum tellus libero ac justo. Vivamus non quam. In suscipit faucibus urna. </p>
  </div>
  <h3>Section 3</h3>
  <div>
    <p>Nam enim risus, molestie et, porta ac, aliquam ac, risus. Quisque lobortis. Phasellus pellentesque purus in massa. Aenean in pede. Phasellus ac libero ac tellus pellentesque semper. Sed ac felis. Sed commodo, magna quis lacinia ornare, quam ante aliquam nisi, eu iaculis leo purus venenatis dui. </p>
    <ul>
      <li>List item one</li>
      <li>List item two</li>
      <li>List item three</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <h3>Section 4</h3>
  <div>
    <p>Cras dictum. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Aenean lacinia mauris vel est. </p><p>Suspendisse eu nisl. Nullam ut libero. Integer dignissim consequat lectus. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. </p>
  </div>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Well yeah I've seen that example before, I dont see how that helps though since I want a button to toggle the collapse of all my accordions. Preferably base on the js already written and shown in the w3 link. Or do you recommend I start over?

Answer (score 0):

This is it

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <head>

 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">

 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>

 <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>     

 <style>
 .accordion {
     background-color: #eee;
     color: #444;
     cursor: pointer;
     padding: 18px;
     width: 100%;
     border: none;
     text-align: left;
     outline: none;
     font-size: 15px;
     transition: 0.4s;
 }

 .active, .accordion:hover {
     background-color: #ccc;
 }

 .accordion:after {
     content: '\002B';
     color: #777;
     font-weight: bold;
     float: right;
     margin-left: 5px;
 }

 .active:after {
     content: "\2212";
 }

 .panel {
     padding: 0 18px;
     background-color: white;
     max-height: 0;
     overflow: hidden;
     transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
     margin: 0;
 }

 .menu_content{
 padding: 10px 18px;
 }
 </style>

 <script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
     $('.menu_content').click(function(){
         $(this).find('span').toggleClass('glyphicon glyphicon-menu-down').toggleClass('glyphicon glyphicon-menu-up');
     });
 });
 </script>   

 </head>
 <body>

 <button class="btn-default btn-block menu_content" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#menu_content"><h5 class="pull-left">Menu</h5><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-down pull-right"></span></button>

     <div id="menu_content" class="collapse">

         <button class="accordion">Section 1</button>
             <div class="panel">
                 <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>

             </div>

         <button class="accordion">Section 2</button>
             <div class="panel">
                 <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>

             </div>

         <button class="accordion">Section 3</button>
             <div class="panel">
                 <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>

             </div>

     </div>


 <script>
 var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
 var i;

 for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
   acc[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
     this.classList.toggle("active");
     var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
     if (panel.style.maxHeight){
      panel.style.maxHeight = null;
     } else {
       panel.style.maxHeight = panel.scrollHeight + "px";
     } 
   });
 }
 </script>

 </body>
 </html>
```